# For events that require participant approval, where do I change the pop-up message?

Tags: civievent

We have a free event that requires participant approval. We are manually approving and sending confirmations to those who are allowed to attend, however there's some confusion because a message pops-up during the process that says they will receive an email to complete their registration, and that doesn't happen (we don't need it since there's no payment and we've already collected all information). We already have this option turned off, but the message is confusing registrants. Where do I find this message to edit/override it?

Screenshots of the message below, which displays on the Confirmation page and the Thank You page:
[image: screenshot of confirmation page]
[image: screenshot of thank-you page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for grep. Use `grep -r "Once approved, you will receive" templates` in your civicrm folder, and it will tell you it's templates/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.tpl. Similarly grep'ing for the other one it's in ThankYou.tpl in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

On the 'Online Registration' tab of the Event configuration is an option to select "Send Confirmation Email"

Sounds like you want to set that to No.

However I think that will still result in an onscreen messaging saying "Your registration has been processed successfully." which sounds like it would still be incorrect.

If this is the only event running you might be able to use Word Replacement to try overwriting that. Otherwise it would require a tweak to the template I think

Comment: Or if you already have then pls update your Q with more info

Comment: We already have the confirmation message turned off and are sending it manually upon approval. I believe I will need to change the template itself for the pending events, but I'm not sure where to locate that.

Comment: Can you add to your Q a screenshot of the screen where they get the pop up

Comment: Yes done - thanks for the suggestion. It's appearing in two places during the process.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `grep`. Use `grep -r "Once approved, you will receive" templates` in your civicrm folder, and it will tell you it's `templates/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.tpl`. Similarly grep'ing for the other one it's in ThankYou.tpl in the same folder.

Comment: Have you tried Word Replacement per my earlier comment?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I understood they're saying that as per your comment where that would change it for all events, they have more than one event and only want to change the text for what they call "Pending".

Comment: @Demerit thank you! I was able to make the modifications in the correct template files. Not familiar with the grep command so I looked it up - very useful. Please add this is an answer so I can accept. And yes we have a lot of events, this is our first foray into "approval required" for the registration setup.

Comment: if this was the only 'approval required' event then a Word Replacement might have sufficed might'nt it?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I'm not sure - We weren't looking so much to replace as to remove - can this be done using Word Replacement? Is an empty string allowable there?

Comment: You can't put an empty string but you can put a single space character.